# Cancelar evento de input

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo varios `input` en una tabla en los que se aceptan solo números, he creado una función para verificar que sean mayores a cero o que sean diferentes de vació luego de que pierda el foco, el código `javascript` que uso para ese control es:

```
function cambiaCantidad(){
if (document.getElementById("tabProd").rows[indice_fila_tabla].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value!=='') {
    var valorCelda=document.getElementById("tabProd").rows[indice_fila_tabla].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    if (valorCelda>0){
    cambiaValores();
}
    else{
        alert("La cantidad tiene que ser mayor a cero");
        document.getElementById("tabProd").rows[indice_fila_tabla].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value=1;
        cambiaValores();
    }
}
else{
    alert("La cantidad es requerida");
        document.getElementById("tabProd").rows[indice_fila_tabla].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value=1;
        cambiaValores();
}
```

}

Mi pregunta es: Si los input tienen un valor y luego lo cambio por cero o por vacio, como puedo hacer que regrese al valor anterior que tenia,
es decir si tenia el numero 1 y luego lo cambio por cero entonces que regrese al valor anterior (uno)

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero guárdalos en una variable (o varias) y vuelve a asignarle el valor cuando desees.

Comment: Elimine la etiqueta jquery pues no se menciona en la prgunta ni se utiliza en el código.

Comment: puse esa etiqueta por si se podía hacer con jquery

Comment: Las etiquetas no se usan para agregar información a la pregunta. Si estás buscando usar jQuery menciónalo en el cuerpo de la pregunta pero también incluye una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado sobre este para resolver tur pregunta. Haciendo estoy ya podrías agregar la etiqueta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes guardar el valor anterior en un atributo del input, con un codigo asi:

```js
function verificarValor(input){
 if(input.value == "" || parseInt(input.value) <= 0){
  input.value = input.getAttribute("valorAnterior");
 }else{
  input.setAttribute("valorAnterior",input.value);
 }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="verificarValor(this);" valorAnterior="1" value="">
```

Comment: me sirvio mucho gracias por la ayuda y perdon por la demora en revisar la respuesta

Comment: No hay por que, me alegro de que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Guarda el valor en una variable, si se trata de muchos valores podrías usar un array.

A continuación un ejemplo simple usando eventos "click"

```js
//Inicializar
var valorAnterior = 0;

//Agregar monitores de eventos
document.getElementById('botonG').addEventListener('click', guardar);
document.getElementById('botonD').addEventListener('click', deshacer);

//Funciones de eventos

// Guarda el valor en una variable global
function guardar() {
  valorAnterior = document.getElementById('entrada').value;
  console.info(valorAnterior);
}

// Deshace el cambio realizado, es decir, asigna el valor en la variable global que fue guardado.
function deshacer() {
  document.getElementById('entrada').value = valorAnterior;
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada" type="number">
<input id="botonG" type="button" value="Guardar">
<input id="botonD" type="button" value="Deshacer">
```

A continuación un segundo ejemplo que en lugar de usar botones usa el evento input.

```js
// Inicializar
var entrada = document.getElementById('entrada');
var valorAnterior = 0;

// Agrevar monitor de cambios de elementos input
entrada.addEventListener('input', control);

// En caso de que se ingrese una cadena vacía o un 0 se coloca el valor anterior
function control() {
  var valor = entrada.value;
  if (valor == "") {
    entrada.value = valorAnterior;
    console.info('Se agregó valor anterior');
  }
  valorAnterior = entrada.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada" type="number">
```

Comment: Pero es una tabla y tiene varios input en este caso eso me serviria para uno pero no para la cantidad variable que se generan

Comment: @LeoT El concepto básico aplica igual si es una o muchas variables, se deben guardar los valores "anteriores" en algún lado para que puedas ponerlos de nuevo. En lo que respecta a tu pregunta edítala para agregar que se trata de una tabla que tiene varios input y lo que has intentado.